# Convert arrays and tensors to matrices then perform matrix operations

Tags: python, tensorflow, matrix, keras, matrix-multiplication

I have two arrays of size (128,) and a third one of size (784, 128):

```
array1.shape()
out: (128,)
array2.shape()
out: (128,)
array3.shape()
out: (784,128)
```

They have the same data type but the `dtype()` output is different:

```
array1.dtype
out: float32
array2.dtype
out: <dtype: 'float32'>
array2.dtype
out: <dtype: 'float32'>
```

And they belong to different classes:

```
type(array1)
out: <class 'numpy.ndarray'>
type(array2)
out: <class 'tensorflow.python.ops.resource_variable_ops.ResourceVariable'>
type(array3)
out: <class 'tensorflow.python.ops.resource_variable_ops.ResourceVariable'>
```

I want to perform the following matrix operation:

```
(array1 - array2) * array3.T
```

Where T is the transpose of array3.

Lastly, the output matrix (which is [784 * 1]) needs to be reshaped to become a uint8 array of shape 28 * 28 so I can `plot` that output on a `matplotlip`.

Can anyone help me to convert the arrays into matrices first. Then Transpose the third array properly. Finally, reshape the output to become an uint8 array of size 28 * 28.

I am working with tensorflow and keras in python.

Answer (score 0):

Cast array1 as `np.asmatrix()`

```
array1 = np.asmatrix(array1)
```

For array2, change it to numpy array fist then cast it as a matrix:

```
array2 = array2.numpy()
array2 = np.asmatrix(array2)
```

For array3, change it to numpy array first then cast it as a matrix. Lastly, transpose that matrix:

```
array3 = array3.numpy()
array3 = np.asmatrix(array3)
array3 = np.transpose(array3)
```

Finally, apply the matrix operation:

```
result = (array1 - array2) * array3
```

To plot the output, use the following:

```
result = np.array(result)
plt.imshow(result.reshape(28, 28), cmap='gray')
plt.show()
```